# How to parse extra attribute from rss xml with read

Tags: xml, bash, rss

I want to parse data from Jackett, initially I tried with flexget but I need to extract data that is not present on various plug-ins, so I started with this little script in order to try to parse those extra data.
My rss is some like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:torznab="http://torznab.com/schemas/2015/feed">
  <channel>
    <atom:link href="http://jackett:9117/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <title>site description</title>
    <description>A general italian tracker</description>
    <link>https://site.some/</link>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <category>search</category>
    <image>
      <url>http://jackett:9117/logos/site.png</url>
      <title>site description</title>
      <link>https://site.some/</link>
      <description>site description</description>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>Pinnacle Studio Ultimate v23 0 1 177 64 Bit Content Pack</title>
      <guid>https://site.some/index.php?page=torrent-details&amp;id=id</guid>
      <jackettindexer id="site">site description</jackettindexer>
      <comments>https://site.some/index.php?page=torrent-details&amp;id=id</comments>
      <pubDate>Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:47:48 +0200</pubDate>
      <size>4778150912</size>
      <grabs>4</grabs>
      <description />
      <link>http://jackett:9117/dl/site/?jackett_apikey=apikey&amp;path=Q2ZESjhIOTlRbnNBaTlsTXBueG41dVNtYWFqVjlsbTFockNDVXRieE5OYXRQYTdnclc4Zmc2dGJVNlFiQ01SVW9Wbm9yblJaZnhWXy0wSnVocHRISGxkYmNQLVQ5aWh6S1RORWtqMmwzMTlvTUFNZHlrV1c2czBlbjhNczlFa3VuQ1RxVjRsTkM0UGxRc2RUYzllR0tJaTBVMFFtMWc0UHIybnl0eFVkbGZqcUxuR1BPRDN0MGYwWUNNcVZ5d3NWazgta0Z0SkdrUUZIYnpZZWpUOTA1V2F5b1JGMEpTWlZVSzN0bVkzYzFMU09BLTlBck54bERpRU0yZ3lNTzkwcDU3amhNWE1MOXZmWFhLSEJaa1gwWEpWMHFYUFRfMFMtSlJQX05oalRMNmtpTlc4S0NueDF6c1VZazZfTkg0bE1IZFF5cEE&amp;file=Pinnacle+Studio+Ultimate+v23+0+1+177+64+Bit+Content+Pack</link>
      <category>4010</category>
      <category>100007</category>
      <enclosure url="http://jackett:9117/dl/site/?jackett_apikey=apikey&amp;path=Q2ZESjhIOTlRbnNBaTlsTXBueG41dVNtYWFqVjlsbTFockNDVXRieE5OYXRQYTdnclc4Zmc2dGJVNlFiQ01SVW9Wbm9yblJaZnhWXy0wSnVocHRISGxkYmNQLVQ5aWh6S1RORWtqMmwzMTlvTUFNZHlrV1c2czBlbjhNczlFa3VuQ1RxVjRsTkM0UGxRc2RUYzllR0tJaTBVMFFtMWc0UHIybnl0eFVkbGZqcUxuR1BPRDN0MGYwWUNNcVZ5d3NWazgta0Z0SkdrUUZIYnpZZWpUOTA1V2F5b1JGMEpTWlZVSzN0bVkzYzFMU09BLTlBck54bERpRU0yZ3lNTzkwcDU3amhNWE1MOXZmWFhLSEJaa1gwWEpWMHFYUFRfMFMtSlJQX05oalRMNmtpTlc4S0NueDF6c1VZazZfTkg0bE1IZFF5cEE&amp;file=Pinnacle+Studio+Ultimate+v23+0+1+177+64+Bit+Content+Pack" length="4778150912" type="application/x-bittorrent" />
      <torznab:attr name="category" value="4010" />
      <torznab:attr name="category" value="100007" />
      <torznab:attr name="seeders" value="4" />
      <torznab:attr name="peers" value="6" />
      <torznab:attr name="minimumratio" value="1" />
      <torznab:attr name="minimumseedtime" value="172800" />
      <torznab:attr name="downloadvolumefactor" value="1" />
      <torznab:attr name="uploadvolumefactor" value="1" />
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

So initially my first idea was to parse each  section in order to extract info, so I came up with this

```
#!/bin/bash

xmlgetnext () {
   local IFS='>'
   read -d '<' TAG VALUE
}

# /data/Varie/Scripts/mmm


cat /data/Varie/Scripts/mmm | while xmlgetnext ; do
   case $TAG in
      'item')
         title=''
         link=''
         description=''
         downloadvolumefactor=''
         ;;
      'title')
         title="$VALUE"
         ;;
      'link')
         link="$VALUE"
         ;;
      'downloadvolumefactor')
         downloadvolumefactor="$VALUE"
         ;;
      '/item')
         cat<<EOF
------------------------------
Title: $title
Link: $link
Custom value: $downloadvolumefactor
------------------------------
EOF
         ;;
      esac
done
```

So **read** start after first < and read till the next < then set **TAG** and **VALUE**

Till here is ok to me, the problem is I can't find a way to extract downloadvolumefactor, because the value is not formatted like standard.

My very first idea is to modify the rss before parse it, so maybe I can transform with a replacing regex

```
<torznab:attr name="uploadvolumefactor" value="1" />
```

into

```
<downloadvolumefactor>1</downloadvolumefactor>
```

Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?

Comment: I don't want to install other tools, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple `awk` (standard Linux gnu awk or gawk) script that solve the problem scanning the input file as pure text.

`script.awk`

```
match($0,"<title>[^<]*", arr) {title=substr(arr[0],8)}   # read title line
match($0,"<link>[^<]*", arr) {link=substr(arr[0],7)}     # read link line
match($0,/uploadvolumefactor" value="[^"]/, arr) {valueFactor=substr(arr[0],28)} # read valueFactor line
/<\/item>/ { # ouput values on item element termination
    print "------------------------------";
    print "Title: "title;
    print "Link: "link;
    print "Custom value: "valueFactor;
    print "------------------------------";
}
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.xml
```

Provided the `input.xml` in the question.

output:

```
------------------------------
Title: Pinnacle Studio Ultimate v23 0 1 177 64 Bit Content Pack
Link: http://jackett:9117/dl/site/?jackett_apikey=apikey&amp;path=Q2ZESjhIOTlRbnNBaTlsTXBueG41dVNtYWFqVjlsbTFockNDVXRieE5OYXRQYTdnclc4Zmc2dGJVNlFiQ01SVW9Wbm9yblJaZnhWXy0wSnVocHRISGxkYmNQLVQ5aWh6S1RORWtqMmwzMTlvTUFNZHlrV1c2czBlbjhNczlFa3VuQ1RxVjRsTkM0UGxRc2RUYzllR0tJaTBVMFFtMWc0UHIybnl0eFVkbGZqcUxuR1BPRDN0MGYwWUNNcVZ5d3NWazgta0Z0SkdrUUZIYnpZZWpUOTA1V2F5b1JGMEpTWlZVSzN0bVkzYzFMU09BLTlBck54bERpRU0yZ3lNTzkwcDU3amhNWE1MOXZmWFhLSEJaa1gwWEpWMHFYUFRfMFMtSlJQX05oalRMNmtpTlc4S0NueDF6c1VZazZfTkg0bE1IZFF5cEE&amp;file=Pinnacle+Studio+Ultimate+v23+0+1+177+64+Bit+Content+Pack
Custom value: 1
------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks great tips, I'm searching a pure bash solution without install other software.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml aware tools.

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//*[name()="torznab:attr" and @name="downloadvolumefactor"]/@value)' /data/Varie/Scripts/mmm
```

Will return:

```
1
```

Do not parse xml files using regexes.

If you have to, *when* you have to, it would be just easier to filter it with `awk` or `sed` or `grep` with `cut` and similar:

```
sed -nr '/.*<torznab:attr name="uploadvolumefactor" value="([^"]*).*/s//\1/p' /data/Varie/Scripts/mmm
```

Bash while read loops are extremely slow, it's better to use other tools. If the file format is steady and you can't get `xmllint` or other xml aware tool, I would go with preparsing it with `sed` - read one line, extract information from it, add to hold space, continue reading&parsing up until `</item>` is encountered. But using xml-aware tools will be way secure and less error prone.